# Tensorflow val_loss definition with multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When training a model (with keras), what does the `val_loss` (as it's shown in the keras training log) / `epoch_loss` (as it's shown in tensorboard) metric measure when the model has multiple outputs? And if it matters, then also if those outputs are weighted?
And I mean multiple separate outputs (e.g. 6 tensors of shape `()`), not a single output with multiple values (e.g. 1 tensor with shape `(6)`). <sup>(Though an answer to the latter might be useful for future googlers.)</sup>

I originally thought it would be a weighted average of all the outputs. But my observations do not agree with that guess. Below is a screencap of tensorboard showing the validation loss of each of the outputs, as well as the `epoch_loss` value (also on validation). As you can see, on each output the loss is increasing, yet the `epoch_loss` value is continually decreasing.

I have also confirmed that these metrics match the `val_*` metrics (`val_1_loss`, `val_2_loss`, ..., `val_loss`) shown in the keras training log.

[image: tensorboard output]

*Note that I'm not interested in investigating why the loss increasing or ways to fix the model or anything. I know this is a bad model. This was just one model from a hyperparameter search that I picked as a good example for the question.
Though I am currently using `val_loss` as the hyperparameter search optimization metric, which from this data does not seem like a good idea. I can create my own metric to do a weighted mean of all the outputs, but wanted to understand what `val_loss` is actually measuring.*

Comment: Are you sure the "epoch_N_loss" plots are actually loss plots? If they were, your model looks like it's diverging (loss increasing?). Could you clarify how those plots are generated and what exactly do they contain?

Comment: Yes. I mean unless the tensorflow/keras internals are doing something else. I've got the model configured with `loss='mean_squared_error'`. And the values in the tensorboard screencap match what is output in the verbose training log. The plots are automatically generated by the tensorboard callback using the configured loss metric (it automatically creates a separate plot for each output from the model).

Comment: Are you sure that, logging for every epoch is done instead of logging for every batch of a epoch  ?

Comment: Yes. Especially since these are validation metrics, and validation only happens at the end of the epoch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out how to force Tensorflow into eager mode and attaching a debugger, I found the cause of the discrepancy.

To start off with, the [keras `model.compile()` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) states under the `loss` parameter:

> The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses.

But then the `loss_weights` parameter goes on to add:

> The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the weighted sum of all individual losses, weighted by the loss_weights coefficients.

So according to this, we should be seeing a simple weighted sum. But as is demonstrated in the question, this isn't the case. So there has to be another source of loss being factored in.

**The answer in my case was from layer losses.**
Individual layers in the model can have their own losses, which can be accessed via [`layer.losses()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#losses). The loss values from these layers gets summed into the total loss used to optimize the model, and are reported in the `val_loss` metric.
In specifics, I had a layer which was using a regularizer, and the penalties applied by the regularizer are tracked as losses.

Answer (score 1):

> what does the val_loss / epoch_loss metric measure when the model has multiple outputs? 
>   And if it matters, then also if those outputs are weighted?

The loss value is computed as the weighted sum of the losses for the multiple outputs, using the `loss_weights` coefficients. When no weights are defined, the loss is simply a sum of the losses.

Here are the references in the code:

- [Training](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training.py#L224)
- [Training_Utils](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L835)